# How to access/edit iPhone Contacts on computer?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I run Windows 7 (no Outlook available) and don't seem to find any native Address Book application on my computer (it is a work-provided laptop). We use Lotus Notes as our mail application. Because my phone is also used for work, I can't use any iCloud services (security restrictions)

I would like to be able to easily see and edit/manage my contacts on my computer and sync them to/from my iPhone (two-way sync), as I mostly am looking up #s and addresses while at my desk, and don't want to have to manually maintain it all twice, or log onto my phone every time I need an address, and then have to manually type it on my computer. Any suggested applications that will do this? I've looked a bit in the app store, but don't find any.

Also - my apple ID is currently linked to the Sweden App Store (I live in Sweden); if there is an app available in another country, can I create an ID for that country and have apps for both IDs on my device?

Comment: Are you able to add any accounts at all to your phone? Is the restriction just on iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

For synchronization of your Lotus contacts and mail with your iPhone, you can try My Notes app: https://itunes.apple.com/app/my-notes-mobile-client-for/id726998714?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Try iTools for windows, you can export all your contacts from your phone to your computer, plus extra useful services. About that app thing in another country, you could change your country in the Apple ID settings (be sure to disconnect your Credit Card because it won't be accepted when you change the country). Once you've changed the country, go back to App Store, download the apps you don't have in your country, then re-change the country to your country, and connect you credit card again. Voilà!

Answer (score -1):

You can edit Address book directly via browser at http://www.icloud.com if you have iCloud sync enabled.

One can have multiple accounts, but only one is active. An app loaded via account 2 can be used when account 1 is signed in. But for updates, you will need to login with account that downloaded (paid) the app (in this example number 2), you don't see updates for apps from non-logged-in account.

Comment: OP mentions he can't use iCloud on the first paragraph.